# magento 1.8 own extension package empty tgz file

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.8

I am working in a magento 1.8 enviroment and have created a new extension the files are in folders :

```
magento/app/code/local/Package/Module/
-controllers
--IndexController.php
-etc 
--config.xml
```

and

```
magento/app/etc/modules/Package_Module.xml
```

I created an extension in the backend and it creats a `name.tgz` file, a `package.xml` and a `name.xml`. My problem is though the paths in the xml files look right, my .tgz file is just empty with a size of 47bytes.

I am new to magento so can anyone help me?

Greetings from Germany

Comment: I think on creating package, you made a mistake. So only you got an empty package. Make sure you follow http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-create-extension-package-images/

Comment: i followed a tutorial like this.. my problem is not that i dont get an file my problem is my file is empty i tested everything, in content starting with / and without using just directories ... changing the version to change folders i get no clue... and the internet is realy dead for my question... or im to stupid to google :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the target paths as shown in the below image and let me know if it didnt work 
[image]

Comment: didnt work same as usual empty tgz file package.xml and name.xml is generated

Comment: After giving the path for the files, are you clicking on load local package button? Because it is compulsory of clicking on it. Then only you files will be copied to the new package. After giving path in the CONTENTS Block, We need to click on LOAD LOCAL PACKAGE and then Click on SAVE AND CREATE PACKAGE..

Comment: First delete the previous folder in that var/CONNECT folder which is not useful.. Then we can know which is the correct one or else it will rewrite on it.. Make sure you clear it

Comment: I deleted the old folders, went to content managed content clicked then on Load local Package clicked then on save and create package.. new files were in folder, tgz still empty with size of 47bytes

Comment: still have no clue what is wrong at me but i found a solution i needed the package for modman which i like to use for simple install and maintaining extensions. and i think a similar solution could also be... i got the package xml with the correct info and an empty tgz file. so i just made a new tgz file with same name where i out my structure and files in ... a little complicated but worked for me :) thanks to all friendly helpers :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is how I fixed it.

I checked my system.log and found this:

> 2016-05-14T05:11:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: md5_file(./app/code/community/LeadGrid/Widget/etc/config.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/magento/lib/Mage/Connect/Package.php on line 643

So you must have all the files of your extension properly installed in your Magento folder. When packaging your extension, Magento looks for the files you specified in the Package Manager.